# How can i redirect from new url to previous url in webview using angularjs?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

How can i redirect from new url to previous url in webview using angularjs?

My code

```
 window.open("https://stage2.pledgster.net/fbapp/", "_blank", "location=no");
```

i am using this code for open this URL in Webview using Angularjs.
 Any solution.?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `$window` which will also refresh the page.
2. You can "stay inside" the single page app and use $location in which case you can choose between `$location.path(YOUR_URL);` or `$location.url(YOUR_URL);`

   Use below code to redirect to new page `$window.location.href = 'https://stage2.pledgster.net/fbapp/';`

Comment: when go on this url then click on a button and facebook login page will open then after successfull login it will come again on this url, so it working in browser but not in webview

Comment: how can i use this method in Angularjs?

Comment: `Webview` is android code .Your `webview` is suppressed `js` code .

Comment: webview supporting also angularjs